# Creating class object defined in another project

Tags: c++, class, constructor, solution

I have a Visual C++ solution with 2 projects: **rectangle** and **project3**.

In rectangle project I have **rect.cpp** and **rect.h**.

rect.h

```
#ifndef rect_h
#define rect_h
class Rect
{
public:
    Rect();

    int m_h;
    int m_w;
};
#endif //rect_h
```

rect.cpp

```
#include "rect.h"
Rect::Rect()
{
    m_h = 1;
    m_w = 5;
}
```

whenever I try to create rect object from the rectangle project it succeeds.

But when I try to do the same from the project3 it produces a linker error.

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Rect::Rect(void)" (??0Rect@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Users\mbaro\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Project2\Debug\Project3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals

main.cpp (in project 3)

```
#include "rect.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rect* a = new Rect();

    return 0;
}
```

I kind of feel that class definition is picked up successfully, but the linker can not link the constructor code from rect.cpp.

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the .h and .cpp files to the second project?

Comment: I have added only the header file file in project properties -> additional include directories. And whenever I build the solution the first one builds successfully and the second produces the linker error.

Comment: OK.  You also need to add the source file so the compiler know to compile it and the linker know to link to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, how to add the source file and where?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfkfe6sy.aspx

Comment: @NathanOliver, I it does not work. It says: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138341/discussion-between-mbaros-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: If you do not want to add the `.cpp` files of project **rectangle** to **project3** you can build **rectangle** as a static library and link to it. Then you can just reference the headers in **project3**.

Comment: Duplication of source files will make future maintenance a nightmare...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is normal: you told the compiler where it could find the .h files, but you did not tell the linker where it could find the .obj files.

It may depend on the exact VS version, but in Project/Properties, you should find Linker/Input and there Additional dependencies. If you only need one or two object files (`xxx.obj`) from the other project, add them here. That way, you avoid code duplication, which will be a nightmare for future maintenance...

If you have many common files, you should considere to put them in an auxilliary project that would build a (static)library in the same solution, and then link the library in both project (and of course give access to header files of the library project for the other projects using the library).

Comment: Serge Ballesta, what do you mean by " one or two .o"? Object file?

Comment: Yes `.o` files (`.obj` from Visual Studio) are object/intermediate files.

Comment: @mbaros : oups, my last dev system was Unix... Of course I meant object files, that is .obj files in VS (thank to ssel for saying that first...)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, thanks. I am trying to do that. After changing the rect project to be static library, now I receive linker error of one or multiple defined symbols. I am trying to figure it out. It is a must for me to have both projects in a single solution.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, what I did and that actually worked is that I have build a dynamic library and declared the class as _declspec dllexport.

Answer (score -2):

I have already started writing a long, long answer. Then i realized, what You may be missing is that despite Your class is named "Person" the header file You should have added is named "rect.h".

Also Your constructor cannot have a declaration of values in the header file (EDIT:not true, I was mistaken). In the header file, try using:

```
Person(int h, int w);
```

You declare what will be needed, not what You already have. If You want those to be specifically what You wrote the constructor should be:

```
Person();
```

in .h

and

```
Person::Person()
{
m_h = 1;
m_w = 5;
}
```

in .cpp.

If You need more detailed description of using include, I have already written a big part of it, so don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Prusio, thanks for the answer. First, I am very sorry for the messed code. I have messed lot of things with copy paste. I changed everyhing "person" related to "rect". Second, I addressed some of your comments (i.e. removed arguments from constructor). Can you please update your answer with the new variable names. Third, It still gives me the same linker error. Can you please comment more about the solution. Thanks.

Comment: None of the things mentioned here would lead to a linker error.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to provide default parameters for values in a constructor. What is not fine is to provide only a constructor with partial default parameters. When you supply a constructor, you suppress the implicit generation of a default constructor. So only having `foo(int a, int b = 1)` means you now have no default constructor. But `foo(int a = 3, int b = 1)` would act as the default constructor. Of course sometimes you do not want a default constructor, but that is not the norm. Herb Sutter mentions this briefly [here](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/).

Comment: @ssell - Thank You for correcting, apparently I did not know the mechanism well UnholySheep - Sorry, I was sure the mistakes in naming header files could be the case.