# How to access another project's VS macro $(TargetFileName)?

Tags: c++, c, xml, visual-studio-2019, c-preprocessor

In Visual Studio 2019 I have two C++ projects contained in the same Solution:  `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

How to define a `C/C++ Preprocessor Definition` in `ProjectB` ( let's call it: `THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME` ), which **is equal to** the string returned by the VS macro `$(TargetFileName)` in the `ProjectA`  ?

**NOTE**:  *Hardcoding paths in the C/C++ source files is outside the scope of this question.*

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The definition of an "XY problem" is "asking about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem."  This question does meet this definition because I have not listed any of my  attempted solutions to the problem of accessing another project's `$(TargetFileName)`.

Answer (score 0):

To access **another** project's VS macro `$(TargetFileName)` create the following XML file:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFileName_Global>__UNDEFINED__</TargetFileName_Global>
   <TargetFileName_Global Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)TargetFileName.vsmacro')">"$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(SolutionDir)TargetFileName.vsmacro').trim())"</TargetFileName_Global>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

...and name it `Directory.Build.props` and place it into your `Solution Directory` (where your *.sln file resides).

Next, in `Solution Explorer` right-click on the Project**A**'s `Properties` --> `Configuration Properties` --> `Build Events` --> `Pre-Build Event` --> `Command Line` and set it to:

```
set /P "_VSdmy=$(TargetFileName.Replace('"','').trim())" &lt;nul&gt; "$(SolutionDir)TargetFileName.vsmacro" ||(call,)
```

Next, in `Solution Explorer` right-click on the Project**B**'s `Properties` --> `Configuration Properties` --> `C/C++` --> `Preprocessor` --> `Preprocessor Definitions` and add the following code there:

```
THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME=$(TargetFileName_Global);
```

Restart Visual Studio.

Now, you can use the `THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME` preprocessor macro in in Project**B**'s `*.h`, `*.c` and `*.cpp` source files at will.  This macro will be defined as a string of the Project**A**'s target file name.

*Note, that the `THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME` preprocessor macro in Project**B** will have meaningful contents only **after** you build the Project**A**.  Before that happens, this macro will be defined as `__UNDEFINED__`.  After building Project**A** you may have to refresh the `Intellisense` and the `syntax highlighting` of this macro in your source files by performing `Rescan` --> `Rescan Solution` from the context menu.  Forgetting to rescan the solution this way, affects only the `Intellisense` display - it does **not** affect the building of any of the projects.*

It is possible to do this with any other macro in Visual Studio and with multiple macros in multiple projects as well.
However, this method of passing variables between projects will not work with MsBuild versions earlier than v15.0 (included in Visual Studio starting from version v2017), because older versions ignore the `Directory.Build.props` file.  See the "Updates" section, in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0?view=vs-2019).
This method will also not work when the MsBuild property `ImportDirectoryBuildTargets` is set to false.

*P.S.

It is also possible to instantly pass a value of an MSBuild variable between projects using the Windows Registry (even through volatile registry keys), however it is not possible to pass it so through an environment variable set by the `set` command, because environment variables set in this manner do not survive the  termination of the process that had set them.   ...and each project is built by a separate MsBuild process.
 The `<SetEnv...` task has the ability to permanently set an environment variable in the `User Profile` or the `Local Machine` through the `<SetEnv Target=...` attribute, and environment variables set in this manner survive even the reboot, but they are not visible to existing processes (i.e. already running VS) - only to newly spawned processes. Environment variables set by the `<SetEnv...` task without the `Target=...` attribute, do not survive the  termination of the process that had set them, just like the `set` command.*

Answer (score -2):

You can include file witch you need example
my second project name is p2
path in same folder repo

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "../p2/Header.h"
int main(){
    print();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

header file code

```c
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
void print() {
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

And you can cheek this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860144/creating-class-object-defined-in-another-project)

Comment: Your answer does not address accessing the string returned by the VS macro `$(TargetFileName)` in ProjectA. It does not work when I insert `#define THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME $(TargetFileName)` into the file `"../p2/Header.h"`.  It does not work when I add `THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME=R"($(TargetName))"` into the ProjectA's `Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Preprocessor` -> `Preprocessor Definitions`.

Comment: you can try #include you file and add %(PreprocessorDefinitions) into ProjectA's Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor and #define targetfilename

Comment: Hardcoding the TargetFileName is not the subject of this question.  Access to the string returned by the VS macro `$(TargetFileName)` in another project - is.  The statement `#define THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME <SomeHardcodedPath>`  is not the same as `#define THE_OTHER_FILE_NAME $(TargetFileName)`.  Most importantly, it does not access the  VS macro `$(TargetFileName)` at all.

Comment: include the file witch has macro example #include "macro.h"
And you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860144/creating-class-object-defined-in-another-project)

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860144/creating-class-object-defined-in-another-project  does not consider accessing the strings returned by VS macros in another project.  It deals only with sharing hardcoded values in header files between two projects.